# Jquery Post Method works in local but not on the server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I Have a simple function that have to write on the file, it work on my local server but when i deploy it on the server it doesn't write on the file? What is wrong ?

foo.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
         $stringData = $_POST['data'];
         $file = "ciao.txt"; 
         $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
         fwrite($fh, $stringData);
         fclose($fh); 
 }
 ?>
```

function.js

```
function WriteToFile() 
{
    var data = "foo baaar";
    $.post("JS/foo.php", {data: data}, function(result){ alert("label updated!!");}, "json");
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Are you sure that you have the right folder/file permissions on the server?

Comment: Yes, check permission for writing. Or use `mkdir()` to create directory with needed permissions and create file there.

Comment: Can you paste some error/warning messages?

Comment: i have no error only that ciao.txt non è aggiornato con la stringa "foo baaar"

Comment: the ciao.txt is not updated with the string "foo baaar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
         $stringData = $_POST['data'];
         $file = "ciao.txt"; 
         $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
         fwrite($fh, $stringData);
         fclose($fh); 
 }
 ?>
```

fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error. 
change fwrite($fh, $stringData);

$written = fwrite($fh, $stringData);
print $written;

now you can get weather your data is getting written or not.

or you may set file permission using php code
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);//750 or do testing with 777 ,then revert to 750 or what your admin suggest

/* try this one */

```
 if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
             $stringData = $_POST['data'];
             $file = "ciao.txt"; 
             chmod($file, 0755);
             $fh = fopen($file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
             fwrite($fh, $stringData);
             $written = fwrite($fh, $stringData);
             print $written;
             fclose($fh); 
     }
```

Comment: the problem is i don't want to know what i'm writing i just want to write in the ciao.txt

Comment: if you try to print what you have written ,you will have actual view weather your writing is successful or not.Do this line  print $written;
 shows something? then you can get what causing failure

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permission on the server. Make it writable.

Comment: how can i do that? the server is not mine :) is the serve of my company

Comment: If you have FTP ( eg : Filezilla ) , just right click the file & choose file permissions and tick all permissions.

Comment: i can connect to the server only trought putty can i set the permission there?

Comment: i change the permission trought shell to 777 but i still have the same problem... maybe the url is not correctly set

Comment: all the file are like that rw-rw-r-- 1 davide 
but the folders with the php file and txt file are like that :
drwxrwxr-x 3 ("another name")

Comment: check that ur php & txt files are on the same directory. If it is different, give appropriate file path to  $file = "ciao.txt";

Comment: php file and txt file are in the same directory